# What extra step am I missing when trying to pass a function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, parameters

I'm trying to insert the function dealIt() into the function dealFlop() so I can access the shuffle function within the dealIt() function. I'm currently receiving the error that shuffle is not defined when I try to use it in the dealFlop() function at

> let freshDeck_04 = shuffle(loadedDeck_03)

; Any help would be awesome, Thank you.

Note: Click: Click Button to deal, and then Flop

```js
function begin() {
  document.querySelector(".introScreen").style = "transition: transform 3s;transform:matrix3d(1,0,0,0,-1.8,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,3000,3000,0,1)"
}
let p1Pot = 5+5;
let p2Pot = 6+6;
let p3Pot = 7+7;
let p4Pot = 8+8;


let playerone = document.querySelector(".dealItP1");
let playertwo = document.querySelector(".dealItP2");
let playerthree = document.querySelector(".dealItP3");
let playerfour = document.querySelector(".dealItP4");
let getP1Pot = document.querySelector(".P1").children[0];
let getP2Pot = document.querySelector(".P2").children[1];
let getP3Pot = document.querySelector(".P3").children[0];
let getP4Pot = document.querySelector(".P4").children[0];
let getFlopInterface = document.querySelector(".flopIt");
let getTurnInterface = document.querySelector(".turnIt");
let getRiverInterface = document.querySelector(".riverIt");


//for loop for bet loop 
//let a = for(i=0; thisFunction(); i++){};

let deck = ["2 Club", "2 Spade", "2 Diamond", "2 Heart", "3 Club", "3 Spade", "3 Diamond", "3 Heart", "4 Club", "4 Spade", "4 Diamond", "4 Heart", "5 Club", "5 Spade", "5 Diamond", "5 Heart", "6 Club", "6 Spade", "6 Diamond", "6 Heart", "7 Club", "7 Spade", "7 Diamond", "7 Heart", "8 Club", "8 Spade", "8 Diamond", "8 Heart", "9 Club", "9 Spade", "9 Diamond", "9 Heart", "10 Club", "10 Spade", "10 Diamond", "10 Heart", "Jack Club", "Jack Spade", "Jack Diamond", "Jack Heart", "Queen Club", "Queen Spade", "Queen Diamond", "Queen Heart", "King Club", "King Spade", "King Diamond", "King Heart", "Ace Club", "Ace Spade", "Ace Diamond", "Ace Heart"];


function dealIt() {
function shuffle(array) {
    var m = array.length,
      t, i;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle…
    while (m) {

      // Pick a remaining element…
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

      // And swap it with the current element.
      t = array[m];
      array[m] = array[i];
      array[i] = t;
    }

    return array
  }

 
  //Player One 
  var arr = deck;
  let freshDeck_00 = shuffle(arr); //length = 52 *Working* shuffled//
  let p1Deal = freshDeck_00.filter(function (value, index, arr) {
    return index < 2;
  }); //length=2 *Working* PlayerOne delt cards// 
  let loadedDeck_00 = p1Deal.filter(x => !freshDeck_00.includes(x)).concat(freshDeck_00.filter(x => !p1Deal.includes(x)));
  playerone.innerHTML = p1Deal;

  //Player Two 
  let freshDeck_01 = shuffle(loadedDeck_00);
  let p2Deal = freshDeck_01.filter(function (value, index, arr) {
    return index < 2;
  });
  let loadedDeck_01 = p2Deal.filter(x => !freshDeck_01.includes(x)).concat(freshDeck_01.filter(x => !p2Deal.includes(x)));
  playertwo.innerHTML = p2Deal;

  //Player Three
  let freshDeck_02 = shuffle(loadedDeck_01);
  let p3Deal = freshDeck_02.filter(function (value, index, arr) {
    return index < 2;
  });
  let loadedDeck_02 = p3Deal.filter(x => !freshDeck_02.includes(x)).concat(freshDeck_02.filter(x => !p3Deal.includes(x)));
  playerthree.innerHTML = p3Deal;

  //Player Four
  let freshDeck_03 = shuffle(loadedDeck_02);
  let p4Deal = freshDeck_03.filter(function (value, index, arr) {
    return index < 2;
  });
  let loadedDeck_03 = p4Deal.filter(x => !freshDeck_03.includes(x)).concat(freshDeck_03.filter(x => !p4Deal.includes(x)));
  playerfour.innerHTML = p4Deal;
 

 



 

  //Deal Player One Through Four
  getP1Pot.innerHTML = 'User Pot:' + p1Pot;
  getP2Pot.innerHTML = 'P2 Pot:' + p2Pot;
  getP3Pot.innerHTML = 'P3 Pot:' + p3Pot;
  getP4Pot.innerHTML = 'P4 Pot:' + p4Pot;
 
 
 


}

function dealFlop(dealIt){
//The Flop
  let freshDeck_04 = shuffle(loadedDeck_03);
  let theFlop = freshDeck_04.filter(function (value, index, arr) {
    return index < 3;
  });
  let loadedDeck_04 = theFlop.filter(x => !freshDeck_04.includes(x)).concat(freshDeck_04.filter(x => !theFlop.includes(x)));
  getFlopInterface.innerHTML = theFlop;

}







function pingThisIn01() {
 let fold = [false];
  let call = [true];
  let raise_01 = [true, 20];
  let raise_02 = [true, 50];
  let dealBets = {
    fold: fold.valueOf(),
    call: call.valueOf(),
    raiseFifty: raise_02.valueOf(),
    raiseTwenty: raise_01.valueOf()
  };
  document.querySelector(".P2").innerHTML = dealBets.call + dealBets.raiseTwenty;
  document.querySelector(".P3").innerHTML = dealBets.fold;
  document.querySelector(".P4").innerHTML = dealBets.raiseFifty;

 
 

}
```

```css
.elTorro{
 box-sizing: border-box; border: 3px solid green; background-image: url("../images(1)/bullface.png");height: 45%;width: 45%;position: absolute; top: 45%;left: 45%;background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
}
.main{
 z-index: -1;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px solid green;
 height: 1000px;
 width: 1000px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 90%;
 
 
}
.introScreen{box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 3px solid green;
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     background-color: yellow;}
 
.title{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 left: 50%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity:10%0;
 font-family: coniferous, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
}
.P1{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 45%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;
 z-index: 1;
}

.p1BetForm{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 65%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;
}
.playersBetForm{box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 45%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;}


.P2{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 10%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity:100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;
 z-index: 1;
}
.P3{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 45%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size:1.5em;
 color: red;
 z-index: 1;
}
.P4{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 80%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;
 z-index: 1;
}

.dealBet{box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 75%;
 left: 5%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;}

.flopIt{box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 300px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 55%;
 left: 20%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;}

.flopBet{box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 75%;
 left: 35%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;}

.turnIt{box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 300px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 55%;
 left: 35%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;}

.turnBet{box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 75%;
 left: 50%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;}


.riverIt{box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 300px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 55%;
 left: 65%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;}

.riverBet{box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 75%;
 left: 80%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: red;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="../CSS/pokerTryOne.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 
 <div class="main"><div class="elTorro"></div>
  <!--<div class="output02" style="z-index: 1; box-sizing: border-box; border: 7px dashed orange;height: 200px; width: 225px; position: absolute; top: 35%; left: 35%;font-size: 5em;color:darkred;background-color: white;"></div>
 <div class="output" style="z-index: 1; box-sizing: border-box; border: 7px dashed orange;height: 200px; width: 225px; position: absolute; top: 75%; left: 35%;font-size: 5em;color:darkred;background-color: white;"></div>
 <input style="box-sizing: border-box; 4px solid green;height: 50px; width: 600px; position: absolute; top:10%; left:10%; z-index: 1; background-color: white; color: darkred;" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="slider01">-->

 <div class="introScreen" >
  
   <button onClick="begin()"> Hello Please Begin</button><p>Here is my video:</p>
  
    <div style="position: absolute; box-sizing: border-box; border: 7px solid green; height: 2000px; width: 2000px; top: 10%; left: 90%;"><img SRC="../images(1)/PortalHuman01Gif.gif"></div>

    </div>
 
 
 <header><h1 class="title">Buttons:<button onClick="dealIt()">Click Button to Deal</button></h1>
   <h1> <button onClick="dealFlop()">Flop</button></h1>
   <h1> <button onClick="dealTurn()">Turn</button></h1>
   <h1> <button onClick="dealRiver()">River</button></h1>
  </header>
 
   <div class="P1"><p>Pot:</p><div class="dealItP1">User</div>
  
   <form id="playerOneForm" action="pokerTryOne.php" method="post">
    
    <label>label:01</label>
    <input id="label01" name="label01" type="range" value="#" max="#" min="#">
    
    </form>
  

  
   </div>
  
    
  
  
  
  
  
   <div class="P2"><button onClick="pingThisIn01()">onclick</button><p>Pot:</p><div class="dealItP2">P2</div></div><div class="playersBetForm">Plaayers Bet form</div>
  
   <div class="P3"><p>Pot:</p><div class="dealItP3">P3</div></div>
  
  
   <div class="P4"><p>Pot:</p><div class="dealItP4">P4</div></div>
  
  
  <div class="dealBet">deal Bet</div>
  <div class="flopIt">flop It</div>
  <div class="flopBet">flop bet</div>
  <div class="turnIt">turn It</div>
  <div class="turnBet">turn Bet</div>
  <div class="riverIt">river It</div>
  <div class="riverBet">river Bet</div> 
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/pokerTryOne.js"></script>
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out

```js
function shuffle() {
    // the shuffle function body
}

function dealIt() {
    ...

    let freshDeck_03 = shuffle(loadedDeck_02);

    ...

    return freshDeck_03;
}

function dealFlop(){
    //The Flop
      let freshDeck_04 = shuffle(dealIt());
      let theFlop = freshDeck_04.filter(function (value, index, arr) {
        return index < 3;
      });
      let loadedDeck_04 = theFlop.filter(x => !freshDeck_04.includes(x)).concat(freshDeck_04.filter(x => !theFlop.includes(x)));
      getFlopInterface.innerHTML = theFlop;

}
```

**Note**: I avoid most of the functions code for simplicity, you have to put the rest.

Comment: im trying to access the shuffle function, I don't want to recall the entire dealIt() function, I just want access to the contents. Does that make sense? I did what you recommended but im still receiving the error that shuffle is not defined.

Comment: let dealItFunction = function()  {
function shuffle(array) {...

Comment: function dealFlop(dealItFunction){
 dealItFunction;
//The Flop
  let freshDeck_04 = shuffle(loadedDeck_03);...

Comment: But, why don't you separate the functions? Just define the shuffle function aparts from dealIt and then you can call it from anywhere after defining it.

Comment: Because I still need access to other contents in that dealIt function. Like: loadedDeck_03. Do you know of any reason why I would still be receiving an error if I passed it in the correct way?

Comment: Note: Click: click button to deal, then Flop

Comment: Looking through the code, I see dealFlop function is outside from the dealIt scope, so you can't call shuffle from inside dealFlop. You can refactoring the code and place that function inside the dealIt, or you can return the values you need from the dealIt function and pass it to the dealFlop function.

Comment: How would I return the shuffle function, and the loadedDeck_03 variable?---> return[loadedDeck_03, shuffle]---> was my attempt but I received the error that shuffle wasn't a function

Comment: inside the dealIt function, type 'return loadedDeck_03' and use that variable to pass it to the dealFlop function

Comment: I'm asking how to return the shuffle function. I tried setting it to a variable, and then returning it in an array with loadedDeck_03-->return[loadedDeck_03, shuffleFunction]--, and im getting the error shuffle is not a function. So its being returned as a variable but im trying to use it as a function in the syntax, is there a way to convert in back to a function once I pass it in?

Comment: also, loadedDeck_03 is being passed into the dealFlop function as undefined, is there a way to pass the default value instead of undefined?

Comment: Check my next answer

Comment: when you put let *freshDeck_04 = shuffle(dealIt());* it is cached as a string. I need the array value.I want to save it like this ******console.log(loadedDeck_03);
 return loadedDeck_03;
 
 
 


}

function dealFlop(loadedDeck_03){


//The Flop
  let freshDeck_04 = shuffle(loadedDeck_03);

Comment: im storing shuffle as a constant at this point. i Just need the value loadedDeck_3, when I pass it right now it is undefined

Comment: I don't really understand your requirements. You just have to define shuffle first, then define dealIt, and finally dealFlop. You put the logic inside of them, and just return the values you need.